# Resize dropdown menu in Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

I'm using [Bootstrap 3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) as well as [this material design plugin.](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) I added a dropdown to a navbar. Within the list item of this dropdown-menu, I have a custom "layout". Something like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">

    <div class="row-picture">
        <img class="circle" src="" alt="icon"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="row-content">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Placeholder</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">Placeholder</p>
    </div>

</li>
```

The problem is that when I click the dropdown button, the dropdown menu cuts off the text. I've tried a few different ways of editing the css to change the width following answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449960/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav) and [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881906/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-width) However, none seems to fix my problem. How can I set a custom width to a dropdown menu, so, it doesn't clip my text?

**Edit:** Here's some relevant code:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.5/css/material.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.5/css/material-wfont.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.5/css/ripples.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css"></link>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="header-navigation">
    <div id="nav-bar-container">
      <nav id="nav-bar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div id="nav-item-container" class="container-fluid">
          <div id="drop-down" class="navbar-header">
            <div id="home-button" class="navbar-left">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Brand" src=""></img>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">User Name
           <span class="mdi-navigation-expand-more"></span>
          </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group" id="dropdown-items" role="menu">
                <li class="list-group-item">

                  <div class="row-picture">
                    <img class="circle" src="" alt="icon"></img>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row-content">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Placeholder</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">Placeholder</p>
                  </div>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"> Logout</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.5/js/material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.1.5/js/ripples.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: can you post some code into a codepen or fiddle? that'll help get your question answered more quickly.

Comment: With only bootstrap's styling, I have not been able to recreate the issue: http://www.bootply.com/z4GF8pbeqo . What additional styling does your plugin or any custom CSS add to these elements?

Comment: I'm using the material design styling plugin. I posted the link in the question. I try to incorporate their "list-group" into a dropdown menu. To make the text appear to the right of the picture as a single list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is a great library but it does things in a very rigid way with things like dropdowns and modal windows. I find myself having to work around it sometimes when what I want to do falls outside the paradigm they are working with. One way to do what you want is to  **make your css as specific as possible** so that you can override the bootstrap css selector.

for example instead of just

`.dropdown .list-group-item{}`

try

```
html body ... [drilling into elements] ... div.dropdown div.list-group-item {}
```

Another thing I do a lot with Bootstrap is use the !important; flag on the css rule that is being picky.

`.dropdown .list-group-item{ width: 400px!important; }`

In many cases I have to do both.

Comment: It did not work and then it did. I wonder why just putting an !important flag and being very specific with the selector made that much of a difference. But it did, thanks!

Comment: The reason it is necessary is because bootstrap has A LOT of css and it can get pretty specific itself. If you are interested I recommend you play with the Bootstrap .less source. It allows you to set your own defaults for many things that you might want to do differently. Plus you will get a chance to see some of their css markup.